# ExtJS 6.7 - How to attach blur and focus events on every form copoment?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'd like to mark each field wrapping container with custom css class when field is focused and remove that class when field is blured. So I would like to attach focus/blur event methods to every form field component I add to any form.

in Ext 4 I did it like this:

```
Ext.ComponentManager.all.on('add', function(map, key, item) {
    // Check if item is a Window and do whatever
    if (item instanceof Ext.form.field.Base) {
        item.on('focus', function(theField) {
            var parentDom = null; //theField.bodyEl.findParent('.x-form-fieldcontainer');
            if (!parentDom) {
                parentDom = theField.bodyEl.findParent('.x-field');
            }
            if (parentDom) {
                var parentEl = Ext.get(parentDom);
                parentEl.addCls('focused-field');
            }
        }, item);
        item.on('blur', function(theField) {
            var parentDom = null; //theField.bodyEl.findParent('.x-form-fieldcontainer');
            if (!parentDom) {
                parentDom = theField.bodyEl.findParent('.x-field');
            }
            if (parentDom) {
                var parentEl = Ext.get(parentDom);
                parentEl.removeCls('focused-field');
            }
        }, item);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to do it in ExtJS 6

Any help appreciated

Regards

Armando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don`t need it, ExtJs has already '.x-field-focus' css class which is added to wrapper element on focus, so you can try to add your styles to the existing class. You can also look at the $form-field-focus-* theme variables..

**Anyway**, if you want to add this functionality, you can override the 'Ext.form.field.Base' class which is the parent of all the form fields.
Something like this:

```
Ext.define('overrides.form.field.Base', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Base',
    
    customCssOnFocus: 'focused-field',
    
    initEvents: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.on('focus', this.addCustomCssOnFocus, this);
        this.on('blur', this.removeCustomCssOnBlur, this);
    },
    
    addCustomCssOnFocus: function() {
        Ext.get(this.getEl().findParent('.x-field')).addCls(this.customCssOnFocus);
    },
    
    removeCustomCssOnBlur: function() {
        Ext.get(this.getEl().findParent('.x-field')).removeCls(this.customCssOnFocus);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for .. thank you ...

Comment: Hm, I have just noticed, it is better to create 3-rd method, something like: get: functuin() { return Ext.get(this.getEl().findParent(‘.x-field’));} and use it in the methods, to keep DRY. And x-field must be some existing property.. in the base class.

Comment: I used x-form-item ... and this works for normal fields .. but if your fields are in field container than the DOM is different and this does not work,  so methods must be fixed to set bacground of that field container not this field parent.